# Data Science and Machine learning: (to handle +ve skew) How to make log transform results positive?

Tags: regression, data-science, skew

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDPyb.jpg)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnR1E.jpg)

The first image is skew distribution and second is after applying Box-cox. Have tried with log transform as well but it gives negative values and same as does Box-cox. How to make it positive? How to relate the transformed labels to original ones?

Comment: Please click on link to view images

Answer (score 1):

How about Yeo-Johnson?

The Yeo–Johnson transformation allows also for zero and negative values of y.

```
yeo.johnson(y, lambda, derivative = 0,
            epsilon = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), inverse = FALSE)
```

[Source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.0-5/topics/yeo.johnson)

Comment: Please click on link to view images

Comment: I am using pandas and python. Is yeo.johnson available with R only? Also, after observing the labels in the first image, what do you think I should use to distribute the data normally?

Comment: I had never heard of the Yeo–Johnson transformation, that is very interesting.